# Get the first half of a string in ruby

Tags: ruby, string

I am trying to get the first half of a string. If the string length is an odd number, then round up. I am bit stuck on getting a half of a string.

```
def get_first_half_of_string(string)
  if string.size % 2 == 0
    string[1,4]
  else
    string[1,5]
  end
end

puts get_first_half_of_string("brilliant")
```

This returns rilli

Comment: Never think of hardcoding a number as the string size. I'm sure you don't want a method to get the first half of this particular string, but of any given string. Then this `string[1,4]` or `string[1,5]` makes no sense at all.

Comment: By the way, a string's first index is 0, not 1. This is the reason why you are missing the `b` in `brilliant`.

Answer (score 2):

When calling `str[start, length]` you need to use `0`, not `1`, as the start point. For the length you should just be able to divide the length by 2, so your method body only needs `string[0, (string.length.to_f / 2).ceil]`

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D

Comment: This is not an array, though. :)

Comment: I was assuming a Ruby `String` is implemented as an array of characters, this seems about right based on the [constructors](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/string.c#L694-L732) and String's [VALUE](https://silverhammermba.github.io/emberb/c/#string), but I'll remove the mention of arrays in the answer as it is superfluous information not needed to answer the question.

Comment: Ugh, why the float conversion and ceiling? Just do `(string.length + 1)/2`

Comment: @Exupery: yep, that mention was indeed irrelevant, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could divide the string size in half and round up if it is odd:

```
half = (string.size/2.to_f).ceil
string[0,half]
```

Comment: Perhaps `/2.0` rather than `/2.to_f`. One could instead write `half = (string.size+1)/2`.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
def first_half_of_string(string)
 index = (string.size.to_f / 2).ceil
 string[0, index]
end

first_half_of_string("brilliant")
#=> "brill"
```

Answer (score 0):

Following previous answers, you could open `String` class:

```
class String
  def first_half
    self[0,(self.size/2.to_f).ceil]
  end
end
```

So you can do:

```
"ruby".first_half
=> "ru"
"hello".first_half
=> "hel"
```

Comment: monkey patching of core classes is usually a bad idea

Comment: @fl00r: very helpful in building basecamp, though :)